# How am I able to open aspx forms inside another aspx forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

The reason why I have to do this is because on another page, it must inherit the dll class name.

E.g. `beePlugInIntegration.index` to make the dll code to work.

However, I cannot simply change the main page inheritance class, because the whole system would crash.

In the end, what I am thinking is to open the sub page in the main page, so I am able to inheritance both class and make the thing works. However what I did is using

```
BeePlugInSection.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/index.aspx"))
```

However it returns me this

```
Server Error in '/WebLITE' Application.

Type 'ASP.index_aspx' does not inherit from `System.Web.UI.UserControl`.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Type 'ASP.index_aspx' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.

Source Error:
```

Can someone help me to open another form class in the aspx?

Comment: Just create a custom control and load it in your index.aspx and anywhere else where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception clearly say

> Type 'ASP.index_aspx' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.

means you have to use [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) not Page.

So create a user control, register it on page or web.config and use it.

Comment: but the inheritance beePlugInIntegration.index class is not belong to the userControl, it is a page

Comment: If you use user control then it is already inherited from UserControl class. You have only 2 options, i.e. cumtom control or user control. Later one is very easy and straight forward.